# Is it possible to calculate Pearson/Spearman correlation of more than two judges in MATLAB?

Tags: correlation, matlab

How is it possible to calculate Pearson/Spearman correlation of more than two judges in MATLAB? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the evaluation of the judges in a matrix X where each column represents one judge and the rows are the corresponding evaluations. Then `corr(x)` gives the required pairwise correlation matrix. From Matlab's help:

> RHO = corr(X) returns a p-by-p matrix containing the pairwise linear correlation coefficient between each pair of columns in the n-by-p matrix X.

Is this what you want?

Comment: I need just one number for all of the judges, not a matrix that shows the pairwise correlations of judges. for example: pearson(a,b,c)=0.53     Is it possible?   Thanks.

Comment: @shadi Correlation is a bivariate relationship in the sense that it tells you the relationship between two sets of variables. Thus, calculating pearson(a,b,c) where I presume a,b,c are different judges is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Pearson correlations can be converted into 'z' scores. Those z scores may be averaged and their median converted back to the composit correlation